# How to make android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground work in API level 8

Tags: android

I have a button code, where in i dont want border for this button, so for that i set propertie `"android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`, but it will not work in API version 8 i.e in Froyo emulator. Please provide me the alternatives.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/serviceContactNumber"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/serviceName"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" 
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true" 
    android:freezesText="true"
    android:textSize="30dip" 
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Borderless buttons are part of the Holo theme which is not available to earlier API versions by default. You can however use [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere) to make the theme available. At this time it does not actually support borderless buttons either but you can get the same effect by setting the buttons background to `android:background="@drawable/list_selector_holo_light"`

if thats too heavyweight a solution either extract the appropriate assets from holoeverywhere or from \android-sdk\platforms\android-16\data\res\drawable and put them into your own project

Comment: If you use ActionBarSherlock, this drawable is already imported as abs__list_selector_holo_light.

Comment: android:background="@drawable/abc_list_selector_holo_light" worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the answer I found in this question works with you: [My app force closes on setcontentview when using the holoeverywhere library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046232/my-app-force-closes-on-setcontentview-when-using-the-holoeverywhere-library)

```
style="?borderlessButtonStyle"
```